# What happened to »grails doc« in grails3?

Tags: grails, groovydoc

The grails 2.x doc feature looks really helpful/promising:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.3/ref/Command%20Line/doc.html

It says that the command »grails doc« - »Generates a user guide and Javadoc + Groovydoc API documentation for the current Grails project.

However, this section of the manual is gone in Grails 3.0.10. I could not find related info in the changelog and the grails interactive console does not know anything about a doc command. I used google but could not find anything about this. (I know about groovydoc and I use it now, but it does not know about the grails innards out-of-the-box, so my question stands)

Where did it go? Why was it removed? Will it come back?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but... You now use gradle groovydoc to generate documentation..

You can also config it in your build.gradle

```
groovydoc {
    destinationDir = new File("${project.docsDir}${File.separator}javadoc")
}
```

check out more here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Groovydoc.html